# pandas reversal of numbers based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d={'name':['edward','margaret'],'sex':['male','female'],'amt':[100,200]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to reverse the amt column if the sex is 'female'. So I need the amt to be -200 for the second record. Something like:

```
df.loc[df['sex']=='female','amt']=-200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, only multiple matched rows by `-1`:

```
df.loc[df['sex']=='female','amt'] *= -1
print (df)
       name     sex  amt
0    edward    male  100
1  margaret  female -200
```

What is simplier version of:

```
df.loc[df['sex']=='female','amt'] = df.loc[df['sex']=='female','amt'] * -1
```